# Checking if array contains given element

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array of numbers and dynamically adding new numbers to that array in for loop. But I need to avoid adding values that already exist in array. Is there a JS native way to check the presence of some value in array without doing 2nd nested loop. I don't want to use nested loop because the size of array may vary up to 10000

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily avoid a for loop by using a while loop. [Pause for laughter...] But seriously, even the built-in [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method (supported by most browsers) probably uses a loop internally.

You could use a plain object instead, and add each number to the object as a property, then afterwards take the values from the object and put them in an actual array (or just use them in the object if that is convenient). Then you only have to loop through the "up to 10000" numbers once at the end:

```
var numbersObj = {},
    numbersArray = [];

// your existing for statement here
for (var i=0; i<something; i++) {
   var currentNumber = somethingElse(); // whatever your existing code is to
                                    // determine the number to add goes here

   // put the number in the object (as a key)
   numersObj[currentNumber] = true;
}

// copy numbers out of object into array
for (var k in numbersObj)
   if (numbersObj.hasOwnProperty(k))
      numbersArray.push(k);
```

After which `numbersArray` contains unique numbers only. The if test with [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is "optional" depending on your point of view.

Within the first loop you could check if `numbersObj` already holds the `currentNumber`:

```
if (!numbersObj[currentNumber])
   numbersObj[currentNumber] = true;
```

Or just (over)write it every time like I did in the first code block.

Comment: great solution :) I really like it

Comment: in this case I even don't need the last for to convert the object to array, because in my case there is no difference where the final values are stored :)

Comment: now in 2017 when we have `Set` support in JS my question seems so funny :)

Answer (score 13):

Just use `includes`.

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(array1.includes(2)); // true
```

Comment: Shortest answer love it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use JavaScript's native `Array.prototype.indexOf`, supported in most browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

```
 var a = [1, 2, 3];
 console.log(a.indexOf(4));   // -1
```

`indexOf` is faster than a for-loop but the algorithmic complexity is still `O(n^2)`. If the size of the array gets much larger, consider a different data structure such as a hash table.

Comment: thanks for your solution, but the other solution fits to my needs more, so I'm checking that one as the answer

Comment: Sounds good. JS objects are just hash maps, which @nnnnnn explicitly showed you how to use. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
function eleContainsInArray(arr,element){
    if(arr != null && arr.length >0){
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i] == element)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: this again uses for loop, which I need to avoid

Answer (score 0):

There is [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which is supported from some browser, you can use this snippets of code to support all browser

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: this uses for loop, I don't want use loops

Comment: @haynar, is this one of these "write a program without using parentheses" type of questions?

Comment: I dont want use explicit loop, I want to use native method because it's more efficient than custom for loop (I know that internally it uses loop)

Comment: @haynar this uses a loppo only if there is no explicit method defined in the browser